# How to fix freezing of Tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I was trying to make an program which imports multiple images(around 600) and gives the user a button which is used to navigate the images.

I have tried to solutions but it didn't worked pretty well for me

The Failed solution 1:-

```
def shower():
    for label in remove_list: label.destroy()
    if x<3:
        img=Image.open(f"{dir_path}\\Files\\Read\\{x}.png")
        img= img.resize((300,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    else:
        img=Image.open(f"{dir_path}\\Files\\Read\\{x}.png")
        img= img.resize((500,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        a=Label(image=img,bg="white")
        a.image = img
        a.place(x=50,y=100)
        a.update()

    left_button_img=Image.open(f"{dir_path}\\Icon\\left button.png")
    left_button_img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(left_button_img)
    leftbutton=Button(image=left_button_img,command=left)
    leftbutton.image = left_button_img
    leftbutton.place(x=300,y=300)
    print(x)
```

The Failed Solution2:

```
The Failed Solution2:
for pngs in range(605):
   img=Image.open(f"{dir_path}\\Files\\Read\\{x}.png")
   img= img.resize((300,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
   img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
   img_list.append(img)
```

In first solution i tried to directly read the image, but it resulted in freezing of tkinter window and closing

and in second solution, i tried to read the images and appended them in a list and then tried to access them but it also resulted in  freezing tkinter window.

any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use ```threading``` module

Comment: And is ```x``` the number

Comment: @Sujay , Can you please tell me how to use that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.after()` method.

```
# The "=0" is just the default value for `number`.
def create_image(dir_path, number=0):
    if number<605:
        img=Image.open(f"{dir_path}\\Files\\Read\\{number}.png")
        img= img.resize((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        img_list.append(img)
        root.after(1, create_image, dir_path, number+1)
create_image(dir_path, number)    #=== Pass what every value you want
```